# what is lebesgue integral of f(x) = n if 0<x<1/n and f(x)=0 otherwise

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Accirding to dominated convergence thm,
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n = \int \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n  $

if I choose f f(x)=n if 0<x<1/n and f(x)=0 o.w. then

$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n = 1, \int \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n =0 $ since $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n $ is $0$ for almost every x . what's wrong?

Comment: What is the main assumption of the **dominated** convergence theorem? Does it really hold in your case?

Comment: To apply dominated convergence theorem, there is a hypothesis you have to check.  You did not do that.  This is a good example to use if you want to show that the hypothesis is needed.

Comment: The assumptions of the dominated convergence theorem are not satisfied.

Comment: every f_n should be bounded by integrable function g, so you mean if I assume f_n is bounded by g, there exist anther f_N s.t. f_N>g, so f_n is not bounded by integrable function. right?